# Rails: Possible to have the migration write the "has_many" into the my_model.rb file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model, migration, relationship

I have 2 models in a simple "belongs_to <-> has_many" relationship.

Using the conventional migration procedure, Rails adds the "belongs_to ..." line to the one model, but not the "has_many ..." line to the other model.

Is it possible to have the migration script add this "has_many ..." line to the other model?
If yes, how exactly would I have to write the generator command?

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I don't believe so, at least not from the default generator.

Comment: @TomDogg check if the `reference` options in migration help something like `post:references`